# webpack 2 babel complied but error on jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-2

What's wrong with my below code?

```
render((
    <FormModal 
        isOpen={true}
        isCompleted={completed}
        onClose={closeModal}
    />
), document.getElementById('ReactApp'));
```

I'm on `webpack 2` and I have below preset for `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Would be a great help if you posted the error you're getting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing react from the presets. My file is like this:

`{
  "presets": ["es2015","stage-0","react"]
}`